# Typescript doesn't infer types for Promise.all()

Tags: typescript, promise, promise.all

Please explain someone the reason and mechanics of that TS doesn't match the types for `a`  (`string` vs `'test'`) matching those for `b` at the same time. How can I solve this? The playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBMAlHAvAPjgbwFBz3GAeyjABc4BtEAXQC5KByUgUzIetThAHcQBLcgAUAToQC2fMMwB0IADZzgFEeMkzhrQnIBuzYE1akGiaolz4iJcgCN6Btpx78hoiVOkawW3fpZsz%20ATEXnIycoQA5qAANHDWZgC%20iEhAA). Thank you in advance.

```js
(async () => {
    const [a]: ['test'] = await Promise.all([Promise.resolve('test')])
    //     ^ type mismatch here
    const b: 'test' = await Promise.resolve('test')
    console.log(a, b)
})()
```

Comment: You'd probably need an `as const` somewhere to get `[Promise<"test">]` -> `["test"]` instead of `Promise<string>[]` -> `string[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be the implementation of the `Promise.resolve()` function. Whoever implemented the typing did not want types to be inferred as narrow as they could be.

```
const c = await Promise.resolve("test")
//    ^? c: string
```

As you can see, when calling `Promise.resolve()` with a string literal, the type is widened to `string`.

Interestingly, this does not happen when giving an explicit type to the variable.

```
const d: "test" = await Promise.resolve("test")
//    ^? d: "test"
```

This behaviour seemed to change in version 3.5 but I am still looking for the changelog which explains this feature.

---

So what are your options?

1. Use `as const` when using `Promise.resolve()`.

```
const [a1] = await Promise.all([Promise.resolve('test' as const)])
//     ^? a1: "test"
```

2. You could write your own wrapper function for `Promise.resolve()` which respects narrow types.

```
type Every =
  | null
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | Array<Every>
  | object
  | symbol
  | undefined
  | {
      [prop: string]: Every
    }

function PromiseResolve<T extends Every>(p: T): Promise<T> {
  return Promise.resolve(p)
}


const [a2] = await Promise.all([PromiseResolve('test')])
//     ^? a2: "test"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBMAlHAvAPjgbwFBz3GAeyjABc4BtEARgF1U4QB3EAS3IAUAnQgW1bABTAHQgANmOAVufASK6CwhMQDdBwAOSlFpDYzAFiZRLUS58Aegv48APQD82c3iIlyVAEz0UjFuzgy-EKiElKBcgBKispqmtpkGiZmNlY2cA5OTjauZAQMzGycPEHy0arqAETxpBXJltb4Gc6GbnAAJgBccFU6Ffl+RbLBCkrlwD1ktc2pjY4AvohImdikEAAOgnAAompcEKjmAD5wUACuEkdwZFysUADml2e8AEaCXJfPhMqCIFCXAIJcLggCAAHh2bwgaEuhGeACtBDBSJdIC9lJdTlA2oIAGa3QRtS44NKUNY8NZda63O60LoQvbNOZOHGYpGsYgBYqRMpqUEAFTgggAHtosQZ6VDgBS4HzEF1wkJ+RhiXAFKRTlwoJyhqVRrE1mY5kA)

Comment: Your `Every` type misses symbols :-)